# Validate Regex in switch true/false

Tags: javascript, regex

One of my switch cases checks this regex

```
regex_y = /[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,20}$/;
str = 'sdsdsdsd:sdsdsdsdd.ssdsdsdsdds';

switch (true) {
    case !regex_y.test(str):
        // do anything
        return false;
        break;
// more switch cases to check
}
```

As the string `sdsdsdsd:sdsdsdsdd.ssdsdsdsdds` contains a `.`and a `:` I need the `str` to be defined as `false` but it is not. Please help me with this. What am I doing wrong?

It kind of looks like that the `str` is check from the beginning after unallowed characters. Same with `sdsdsddsd...dsdsd....sdsdsd`.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: You forgot the `^` at the start. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,20}$/`

Comment: Holy! Oh yes, sorry :) Thanks!